# Error on adding service refrerence to DNN site

Tags: web-services, web, wsdl, service-reference, dotnetnuke

have successfully created a working model interacting with an external web service via a service reference in my Visual Studio dev environment.

I now want to set this up on our Evoq Content Basic site as a DNN module. 
So Step 1 was to add the service reference to dnn, but as soon as the reference was created in the app_webreference folder it brings down our site with the following error below.

> Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'antlr.runtime, >Version=2.7.6.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1790ba318ebc5d56' or one of >its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine >why the assembly 'antlr.runtime, Version=2.7.6.2, Culture=neutral, >PublicKeyToken=1790ba318ebc5d56' could not be loaded. 
>   WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. 
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value >[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. 
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. 
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value >[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

I have never added a web service in DNN before so I am hoping the error will mean something to one of you guys. after all, it should not be that hard? and adding a service reference is the method most DNN tutorials recommend

Comment: I should add that I tried adding the S reference manually by copying the reference folder across and updating the web config but that failed as well so I opened the site in VS on the webserver and added it as per usual method.
Both Failed

Comment: Are you using any dependencies of antlr.runtime ? Is the reference available in DNN bin ?

Comment: I was able to get it working by right clicking on my newly created Service Reference and selecting configure then uncheck tick box for " Reuse types in referenced assemblies ". It took a while for the site to come back up but all is working ok now.. does seem odd behaviour though.

Comment: I could not find any reference to antlr.runtime.  Would you expect to find a reference to the webservice in the bin?